# Mongoose Storing Refs of ObjectId of another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections "Person" and "Stories". Stories Model has a field called restricted. I need to store ObjectId of stories which are not restricted in person schema. Generally to show available story for that person.

## *person.model.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var personSchema = Schema({  
  name    : String, 
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

## *story.model.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema; var
storySchema = Schema({   
 creator  :  String,  
 title    : String,  
 restrictions : Boolean  
});
 var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
```

I am complete new in mean. Please help me find what to write in **person.controller.js**

Comment: "Help me" will usually not get you any answered here. Ask specific questions where you're facing problems and show initial efforts.

Comment: need to store the object id of stories in person model.  Apart from help me i thought my question was clear

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get a list of the distinct ids for stories which are not restricted, you do this using the **[`distinct()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct)** command.

When you get the list of ids then you can update the Person model's stories field with that list using **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** or **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** or **[`update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)**.

An example follows:

```
Story.distinct("_id", { "restrictions": false }).exec(function(err, stories) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Person.findByIdAndUpdate(personId, 
        { "$addToSet": { "stories": { "$each": stories } } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err, person) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(person.stories, null, 4));
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: Is referencing a bad way of storing data in mongo?

Comment: That depends on your application design and is rather a broad topic. For more details on data modelling in MongoDB, please read the docs [Data Modeling Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/), especically [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/). Apart from that, did the above answer solve your issue?